# A is not associated to B

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js

Looked on the internet about similar questions/errors, none of them helped me...

*Unhandled rejection SequelizeEagerLoadingError: Task is not associated to User!*

My users route

```
router.get('', function (req, res) {
  models.User.findAll({
    include: [
      {
        model: models.Task,
        as: 'tasks'
      }
    ]
  }).then(function (users) {
    res.send(users);
  });
});
```

User model

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    first_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    underscored: true
  });

  User.associations = function (models) {
    User.hasMany(models.Task, { as: 'tasks' });
  };

  return User;
};
```

Task model

```
'use strict';

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Task = sequelize.define('Task', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    underscored: true
  });

  Task.associations = function (models) {
    Task.belongsTo(models.User);
  };

  return Task;
};
```

I associate them both, and made a bidirectional relationship..

Comment: Hi yooouuri, were you able to solve this?

Answer (score -1):

As you are using the finder function for association with *as* option, Sequelize cannot find that alias, as it is not defined explicitly anywhere. Please try this one:

```
User.associations = function (models) {
  User.hasMany(models.Task, { as: 'tasks' });
};
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Isnt that what he is trying?